# using colon or semi colon at the end of conditional statements

Tags: punctuation

I want to add a colon or semi-colon after making conditional statements.
Can we do this?

Here are some examples:

> If you wish to go to bed, you can do that now: just brush your teeth, tidy
> up your room and turn off the light.
>
> If you wish to go to bed, you can do that now; it is getting late already.

Comment: I'd say a colon is a *very* poor choice for your context, and a semicolon isn't much better. I'd either start a new sentence with ***Just** brush your teeth...* and ***It** is getting late*, or use an em-dash.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just wanted to emphasize all of these actions that had to be taken. What should I have said if I wanted to use a colon? Can I add, "But you need to do the following first: brush your teeth..."

Comment: Yes - as the first definition in @DialFrost's answer says, *A colon is used to ... **introduce lists***. Note that I *could* reasonably have used a colon instead of a comma after ***says*** in my first sentence here. But the general trend is towards less / "lighter" punctuation, so on *modern* stylistic grounds I much prefer the comma. I think it's better to look for ways of *avoiding* use of the colon, rather than seeking out opportunities to include it in your text.

Comment: Thank you! Oh wow that is a new way of thinking about the use of a colon and semi-colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Definition of colon and when to use it

> A colon is used to give emphasis, present dialogue, introduce lists or text, and clarify composition titles

In this case, you **cannot** use the colon in the first sentence you provided, as there is no emphasis being made here. Plus, the words before the colon do not reference anything after it, example:

> She had one love: Western Michigan University

#### Definition of semi-colon and when to use it

> A semicolon is most commonly used to link (in a single sentence) two independent clauses that are closely related in thought. When a semicolon is used to join two or more ideas (parts) in a sentence, those ideas are then given equal position or rank.

or

> Use a semicolon between two independent clauses that are connected by conjunctive adverbs or transitional phrases.

Following the below as well

> A semicolon can always, in principle, be replaced either by a full stop (yielding two separate sentences) or by the word and (possibly preceded by a joining comma).

We can tell that for the second sentence in your examples, you **can** use the semi-colon

Links/references

- https://wmich.edu/writing/punctuation/colon
- https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/grammarpunct/semicolons/